# Boundary of p(x)-triharmonic operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

Regarding the boundary conditions often associated with this operator, why is the
assumption

$\Delta^{2} u=0$ commonly made, and what are the implications of
this hypothesis for the solution properties of the associated EDPs?